# How to play the same Flare animation on every tap?

Tags: flutter, flare

I'm only able to run the animation when the object is tapped in this way?

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool isOpen = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            isOpen = !isOpen;
          });
        },
        child: FlareActor('assets/heart.flr',
            animation: isOpen ? 'run' : 'x'),
      ),
    );
   }
  }
```

but what I need is to run the same animation on every tap, this doesn't work:

```
GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
          });
        },
        child: FlareActor('assets/heart.flr',
            animation: 'run'),
      )
```

I also tried this:

```
GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            isOpen = !isOpen;
          });
        },
        child: FlareActor('assets/heart.flr',
            animation: isOpen ? 'run' : 'run'),
      )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had the same problem when I was implementing some things. And I got my question answered, You can use the FlareControls and just call play instead of using the keys to play the animation. [Original post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55306137/1463174).

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // Store a reference to some controls for the Flare widget
  final FlareControls controls = FlareControls();

  void _playSuccessAnimation() {
    // Use the controls to trigger an animation.
    controls.play("run");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: FlareActor("assets/heart.flr",
          animation: "run",
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          // Make sure you use the controls with the Flare Actor widget.
          controller: controls),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _playSuccessAnimation,
        tooltip: 'Play',
        child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I also have [a video](https://youtu.be/vsyjMrZa5OU) explaining how to integrate these animations and replay the same one.

Comment: Thanks, it would be better if it solved my main problem (tapping the flare object) but it's OK I got the idea :)